# Converting a ansi blob data in utf8 db to utf8 characterset

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a column in utf8 database which contains ansi data.
This occurs as i am migrating from a non utf8 db to a utf8 db.

The column has blob data. My question is how do i convert this data to utf8 character set from ansi?
Is there any specific query i can run to convert the ansi data to utf8 data?
Or any other means which i can use to do the same??

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: When you say "ANSI data", do you mean "data encoded using the 7-bit ASCII character set, i.e. US7ASCII"?

Comment: Yes it is encoded using 7 bit ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data is currently US7ASCII, you shouldn't need to do anything to it to convert it to AL32UTF8.  The UTF-8 encoding was designed so that characters in the 7-bit ASCII character set have identical binary representations in UTF-8.